# Comic where a boy gets animal powers from t-shirts

Tags: story-identification, comics

It was not DC or Marvel. I distinctly remember him talking to the animal spirts from the shirts. Whenever the shirt got ripped he permanently lost the power. The villains were stealing kids to maybe feed to something? I can't remember for sure. I think his dad was a god and him coming down was a trial for him.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published?

Comment: unfortunately I don't remember exactly when I read it, but probably around 2013 or 2014. and I have no idea when it might have been published

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paul Pope's *[Battling Boy](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1596431458)* as per [this list](https://ccb.ischool.illinois.edu/ka-pow-stories-about-superheroes-september-2014/).

[image: Cover of Battling Boy]

> Haggard West, hero of Acropolis, seems to be the only hope for Acropolis, constantly under siege from horrific monsters, until his untimely death.  Battling Boy, son of gods, then springs onto the scene, armed with a monster guidebook and a collection of T-shirts that help him use animal powers. This graphic novel follows his ascent as the city’s new hero, all while West’s daughter Aurora is using her father’s lab to train herself to take on the monsters.

Found with a search for `"comic book" animal powers "t-shirts"`